# bootstrap popover conditional expression angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have some cells, with an ng-click, that filters the data I get from the API.

So I get from the API a big array, and depeding on what cell I click, that array gets filtered, and its filtered content shown in the popover.

All working great, but I have an issue, when after the filtering the array is empty, because none of the data meets the criteria, I get an empty popover, and what I want, is that if the array is empty, the popover doesnt show up at all!

I thought I found a solution, but it's not optimal, I used:

```
popover-enable="vm.isThereData"
```

and `isThereData` is a `Bool` that returns `false` if the filtered array returns empty:

```
if(this.apiData.activities.length < 1){
                return this.isThereData = false;
            } else {
                return this.isThereData = true;
            }
```

I put this code in my function that filters the array that and that gets called with the ng-click on the cell in the view!

The problem is, as the array with the filtered data gets created on the fly when I click on the cell, the popover will show up on that first click, and only then, my var `isThereData` will get `false` if there was no data, and from there on it will disable the popover to show!

I understand why, before the first click the filtered array has still not been created, so the popover will show, but can't think of a solution.

How can I use `popover-enable` to disable it from showing, if to decide if it needs to be shown or not, I first need to click on a cell to get the filtered data?

I would need somehow that as soon as I click and the new array with the filtered data gets created, THEN it checks for the `popover-enable` and activates or not the popover!

edit: code for display popover on click on the cell:

```
    ng-repeat="month in [].constructor(12) track by $index" 
ng-click="vm.setDataForActivities(t.activity.id, $index+1)" 
popover-class="popoverCustomSize" popover-append-to-body="true" 
popover-placement="bottom-left"
popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" 
popover-enable="vm.isThereData" 
uib-popover-template="'Views/xxx/yyy/popoverTemplate.htm'">
```

and the function to filter data on the ng-click just takes as args the array given by the API with all the data, and filters it by date (each cell is a different date, so when you click on it, the ng-click and this function will filter the data so only the data within the date of the cell will be displayed)

Comment: can you just show(`code`) how you are showing popup in code

Comment: added code to show the popover